# Difference between vector of vectors and custom class

Tags: c++, vector, matrix

I was wondering what the difference (of any kind) is when using a vector of vectors to represent a 2D matrix or make a class like:

```
template < class T > 
class Matrix2D {
public:
    Matrix2D( unsigned m, unsigned n ) : m( m ), n( n ), x( m * n ) {} ;
    Matrix2D( const Matrix2D<T> &matrix ) : m( matrix.m ), n( matrix.n) x( matrix.x ) {} ;
    Matrix2D& operator= ( const Matrix2D<T> &matrix ) ;
    T& operator ()( unsigned i, unsigned j ) ;
    void resize( int nx, int ny ) ;
private:
    unsigned m, n ;
    std::vector< T > x ;         
} ;


template <class T>
T& Matrix2D<T>::operator ()( unsigned i, unsigned j ) {
    return x[ j + n * i ] ;
}

template <class T>
Matrix2D<T>& Matrix2D<T>::operator= ( const Matrix2D<T> &matrix ) {
    m = matrix.m ;
    n = matrix.n ;
    x = matrix.x ;
    return *this ;
}

template <class T>
void Matrix2D<T>::resize( int nx, int ny ) {
    m = nx ;
    n = ny ;
    x.resize( nx * ny ) ;
}
```

Edit: Ignore the resize method, as Erik pointed out it would not keep original data place. I only added for a specific task where I didn't mind. The basic class is just the ctor and the () operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- **-** `.resize()` will not keep existing data in the original positions.
- **-** Syntax differences, `operator()` vs `operator[]`
- **-** No iterators, and no using e.g. `std::` algorithms
- **+** Better locality, backing vector has contiguous memory
- **+** More understandable syntax for initialization
- **+** Guarantees that the array isn't jagged

In short, the class is fine and likely better for specialized purposes, but it's not doing too well on generic-purpose.

Comment: Well ok lets ignore that method, I only added it for a specific task where I didn't mind for data position. The basic class is the ctor and the () operator.

Comment: Well other differences could be different syntax (`[]` vs `()`), lack of iterators, not usable with std:: algorithms... What are you really asking? Your approach will work, and it'll ensure better locality since your backing vector is contiguous.

Comment: Well im using the matrix for numerical computations, and contiguous memory address is one thing im concerned... Vector of vectors doesn't guarantee that? for the time im not using and std::algorithms..

Comment: a single vector has contiguous memory. A vector of vector will have a contiguous array of pointers to other contiguous arrays of T